# selecting multiple counts when tables not directly co-relate

Tags: sql, postgresql

users table:

- user_id (distinct for each user)
- source_id (users may have the same source)

rule tables:

- white_rules
- black_rules
- general_rules

these tables all look the same, and have:

- victim_id (co-relates to user_id from users table).
- rule_id (co-relates to a different table which is not important here)

What i need is to extract the amount of total rules per-type (white,black,general) per-source_id.

example:

- source_id: 5 ---> total 70 white rules, total 32 black rules, total 21 general rules
- source_id: 7 ---> total 2 white rules, total 0 black rules, total 4 general rules

and so on... for all distinct sources that are listed on users table.

what i tried is:

```
SELECT source_id,
count(w.victim_id) as total_white,
count(b.victim_id) as total_black,
count(g.victim_id) as total_general
from users
LEFT JOIN white_rules as w ON (user_id=w.victim_id)
LEFT JOIN black_rules as b ON (user_id=b.victim_id)
LEFT JOIN general_rules as g ON (user_id=g.victim_id)
where deleted='f' and source is not null
group by source;
```

but the result table I get has wrong (higher) numbers than what I expect to get,
so I must be doing something wrong :) 
would appreciate any hinge in the right direction.

Comment: What is `source` that is used in `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do your counts in subqueries, or count distinct, as your multiple 1 to many relationships are causing cross joining. I don't know your data but imagine this scenario:

**Users:**

```
User_ID |   Source_ID
--------+--------------
  1     |      1
```

**White_Rules**

```
Victim_ID | Rule_ID
----------+-------------
   1      |    1
   1      |    2
```

**Black_Rules**

```
Victim_ID | Rule_ID
----------+-------------
   1      |    3
   1      |    4
```

If you run

```
SELECT  Users.User_ID, 
        Users.Source_ID, 
        White_Rules.Rule_ID AS WhiteRuleID, 
        Black_Rules.Rule_ID AS BlackRuleID
FROM    Users
        LEFT JOIN White_Rules
            ON White_Rules.Victim_ID = Users.User_ID
        LEFT JOIN Black_Rules
            ON Black_Rules.Victim_ID = Users.User_ID
```

You will get all combinations of `White_Rules.Rule_ID` and `Black_Rules.Rule_ID`:

```
User_ID | Source_ID | WhiteRuleID | BlackRuleID
--------+-----------+-------------+-------------
  1     |    1      |      1      |      3
  1     |    1      |      2      |      4
  1     |    1      |      1      |      3
  1     |    1      |      2      |      4
```

So counting the results will return 4 white rules and 4 black rules, even though there are only 2 of each.

You should get the required results if you change your query to this:

```
SELECT  Users.Source_ID,
        SUM(COALESCE(w.TotalWhite, 0)) AS TotalWhite,
        SUM(COALESCE(b.TotalBlack, 0)) AS TotalBlack,
        SUM(COALESCE(g.TotalGeneral, 0)) AS TotalGeneral
FROM    Users
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  Victim_ID, COUNT(*) AS TotalWhite
            FROM    White_Rules
            GROUP BY Victim_ID
        ) w
            ON w.Victim_ID = Users.User_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  Victim_ID, COUNT(*) AS TotalBlack
            FROM    Black_Rules
            GROUP BY Victim_ID
        ) b
            ON b.Victim_ID = Users.User_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  Victim_ID, COUNT(*) AS TotalGeneral
            FROM    General_Rules
            GROUP BY Victim_ID
        ) g
            ON g.Victim_ID = Users.User_ID
WHERE   Deleted = 'f'
AND     Source IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Users.Source_ID
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3e26d/5)**

An alternative would be:

```
SELECT  Users.Source_ID,
        COUNT(Rules.TotalWhite) AS TotalWhite,
        COUNT(Rules.TotalBlack) AS TotalBlack,
        COUNT(Rules.TotalGeneral) AS TotalGeneral
FROM    Users
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  Victim_ID, 1 AS TotalWhite, NULL AS TotalBlack, NULL AS TotalGeneral
            FROM    White_Rules
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Victim_ID, NULL AS TotalWhite, 1 AS TotalBlack, NULL AS TotalGeneral
            FROM    Black_Rules
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Victim_ID, NULL AS TotalWhite, NULL AS TotalBlack, 1 AS TotalGeneral
            FROM    General_Rules
        ) Rules
            ON Rules.Victim_ID = Users.User_ID
WHERE   Deleted = 'f'
AND     Source IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Users.Source_ID
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3e26d/3)**